# kdb: check whether a symbol starts with a particular prefix

Tags: kdb

Given a symbol, how to check whether it has a particular prefix?

I had below code. It checks if a symbol begins with `aaaaa` but returns `1b` for `aaa` which is wrong. I can add a length check but that seems verbose. Is there a cleaner way?

```
{"aaaaa"~-5#string x}[`$"aaa"]
```

Comment: Below solutions with `like` are better solution in this case, but for future reference `sublist` is similar to `#` but will take e.g. max 3 in that example. https://code.kx.com/q/ref/sublist/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you use `like`?

```
q)`aaa like "aaa*"
1b 
q)`aaa like "aaaaa*"
0b
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the issue is with "take" since "aaa" is shorter than 5. It's extending "aaa" by 2/3 of itself in order to meet that length.

You could modify your function so you have the following:

```
q){"aaaaa"~(x) til 5}["aaa"]
0b
q){"aaaaa"~(x) til 5}["aaaaaaaa"]
1b
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Matthew's answer if you want to make a function out of it do the following:

```
q)f:{x like "aaaaa*"}
q)f[`aaa]
0b
q)f[`aaaaa]
1b
q)f[`aaaaabcde]
1b
```

And if you want to make it more dynamic you could add a second variable for the matching prefix.

```
q)f2[`aaa;"aaa"]
1b
q)f2:{x like y,"*"}
q)f2[`aaa;"aaaaa"]
0b
q)f2[`aaa;"aaa"]
1b
```

Let me know if you see any issues.